# "Tiere sind auch nur Menschen"....what's therole of "nur" on this phrase?

Tags: translation

I was watching the 10th episode of "Extra" and on minute  2:41 they say the phrase "Tiere sind auch nur Menschen"

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vaW3bWuwgL0

I translated the phrase on Google Translate and the meaning was

> "Animals are people too".....

Then I removed the nur on the phrase and it still meant

> "Animals are people too".....

So...what does that nur brings to the table on this phrase??....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word *nur* has the same sense as *only*, in fact *auch nur ein Mensch* has the same meaning as *only human*. As in that 80s song by the *Human League*.

In both languages it denotes that you're subject to foibles and fallibility.

Just like that famous Latin saying, supposedly by Seneca

> errare humanum est

meaning, of course

> To err is human.

Someone may say

> Ich bin auch **nur ein Mensch**!

which, under pressure on a job and asked to work faster and better may mean *I'm **only one person***, but also *I'm not super-human*.

When found out to have cheated, for an unfair advantage or in a relationship (as in the above-mentioned song), it may mean *I succumbed to temptation*.

But in this specific usage, it's a bit of a two-way street: on one hand the meaning as outlined above. Animals are fallible and make mistakes - so you may see that phrase used in some funny animal video.

But it's also a slight jab against humans that they too are just animals and not the supposed *crown of creation* (Krone der Schöpfung). Or at least I've always taken it to have that hidden connotation.

That's why there are also phrases like (courtesy @Crissov)

> Tiere sind die besseren Menschen

which means

> Animals are the better humans/people

Or

> Frauen sind die besseren Männer

meaning

> Women are the better men

The point being the somewhat ironic phrasing to link two disjunctive groups.

Comment: _Irren ist menschlich_ and _Ich bin auch nur ein Mensch_ are certainly phrases that are related, but I’ve also heard _Tiere sind **die besseren** Menschen_, which is similar to _Frauen sind die besseren Männer_ where you compare two groups that are usually considered disjunct.

Comment: @Crissov Indeed, I'd add that, because it's your first example that I had in the back of my mind - but I can't come up whether there is formal name for this form of construct. "Disjunctive constructs"?

Comment: Hmm, I'm using the word _ironic_ wrong, aren't I? I'm worse than Alannis Morisette and her stupid song. :P